# Angular Math.floor Math.random response issue

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I am doing api with random joke. I have db.json file with some jokes.

```
export class HomeComponent {
  public randomValue:any;
  public jokes: any = [];

  constructor(
    private PagesService: PagesService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadData();
  }

  loadData() {

   this.PagesService.LoadJokes().subscribe(response => {
     console.log(response)
    this.jokes = response
    var randomValue = this.jokes[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.jokes.length)];
    this.randomValue = response
   })
  };

}
```

without

```
var randomValue = this.jokes[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.jokes.length)];
this.randomValue = response
```

it's printing all jokes from my db.so it's working.

The problem is this Math.floor function.
Right now it's printing :

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object].
```

My HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
    {{ randomValue }}
  </div>`
```

I'll be gratefull for any help.

Comment: use `{{randomValue|json}}` and **NOT** use "var". In typescript use "const" or "let" (var makes that the variable becomes global, and we don't want this

Comment: {{randomValue.joke}} may be?

Comment: {{randomValue|json}} it's printing all jokes from my .db.

Comment: The problem it's to get one random joke from my db.

Comment: Here's one joke from my database:{
      "id": "14",
      "category": "black humor",
      "content": "Some Joke."
    }

Comment: this.PagesService.LoadJokes().subscribe(response => {
     console.log(response)
    this.jokes = response--> this part is printing all my jokes. I need one random joke so {{randomValue|json} is working the same as my code

Comment: you're equal this.randomValue to "response" instead of to "randomValue"